# nubbie in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to make a toy system to learn rails, well, I'm with a doubt, can help me?

I am using devise to authenticate. However I will need two profiles within the system.

User and Professional.

User = devise basic information

Profisssional = will have to add various informations.

What better way to create these different profiles?

with a boolean in the model User = 0 User, 1 Professional.

or creating more 1 devise model?

or Another way

Remembering that I'll need to list (array) the registered professional later.

Comment: Devise has plenty documentation on the subject. Just look for it in their Wiki pages.

Comment: Easiest way would be to have 2 separate models: User and Profile , then you can say ` a User has_one Profile ` then in the Profile model you can add a column to differentiate the user, such as: `user_type` which can either be a boolean or integer. 1 = User, 2 = Professional or true = Professional, false = User